# SSRS Expression for hiding the row when a column value = 0

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012, sqldatatypes

I'm attempting to hide a row based on a column having the value 0. The Quantity column is a decimal datatype.

I'm trying `=IIf(Fields!Quantity.Value = 0 True,False)` in row visibility

My error is:

> error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'TruePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.

```
class   |  Quantity | AcctV | ExtVal |
GENERAL |    20     |  49   |  980   |
RETAIL  |    0      |   0   |  0     |   <-- This should be invisible
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing a comma after the zero

```
=IIf(Fields!Quantity.Value = 0, True,False)
```

Actually you can simplify  the whole thing and just use

```
=Fields!Quantity.Value = 0
```

as this will return true or false anyway. No need for IIF

Comment: I've implemented the changes that you suggested however I get the error "The Visibility.Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix2’ contains an error: [BC33104] 'If' operator requires either two or three operands."

Comment: Sorted it, somehow the table glitched and still have a hidden expression even though i had deleted it. Thanks Alan :)

Comment: Can you paste the exact expression you are using. The above should have worked. If you try the second option you don;t even need to use IIF

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield and how to show "---" instead nothing when I get 0 as value

Comment: @Emmanuel_InfTech Ask new question.

Comment: @AlanSchofield https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77761893/show-wanted-string-when-get-an-specific-value-from-datasource-srrs-sql-reporti

Answer (score 1):

If all row datas are zero you can hide row group visibility expression.

```
=IIf((Sum(Fields!Data1.Value) = 0) AND (Sum(Fields!Data2.Value) = 0) AND (Sum(Fields!Data3.Value) = 0) AND (Sum(Fields!Data3.Value) = 0) AND (Sum(Fields!Data4.Value) = 0) AND (Sum(Fields!Data5.Value) = 0) AND (Sum(Fields!Data6.Value) = 0), True,False)
```

[image]

[image]