# Show wanted string when get an specific value from Datasource - SRRS SQL Reporting Services Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, report, reportbuilder, sqlreportingservice

using SQL Reporting Services Report Builder and this code:

`=IIf((Fields!Login_de_Windows.Value = "0"), True,False)`

I hide the result value when I get zero (note: the zero is string type, not numeric).

But I would like to show this: "---" (3 dashes) instead nothing when I get "0" as value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your value expression is something like this

```
=Fields!Login_de_Windows.Value
```

then you just need to change it to something like this.

```
=IIF(
     Fields!Login_de_Windows.Value = "0",
     "---",
     Fields!Login_de_Windows.Value 
     )
```

If this doesn't work, then all we are doing is testing the value of the current expression (whatever that is and returning `--` if it is `"0"`. so the basic syntax is

```
=IIF(<<current textbox expressions here>> = "0", "---", <<current textbox expressions here>>)
```